# Best and fast way to list a local drive's root folders and files and the size of them in php?

Tags: php, directory

E.g:

local drive C:

```
folder1  346MB
folder2  567MB
....
file1    345MB
file2    343MB
....
```

Because I have `thousands` of folder or files in the `local drives` , and I want it to display in the web page and remove them from the web page base on their total access times . and the folders or files which have no access will be deleted!So is it a good way to do that or have others much better!?

Any idea would help!!

**[update]**

I found a windows tool to Calculate folder size from the command line .[Disk Usage v1.34](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx). It is good to return all folder and their's size. And now the question:

```
Which is faster.PHP or the internal command line tool!?
```

Thank yo very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [shell command](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: of course there is a whole stack of batch-commands. but I don't know which would do the job. you will find lists with windows-commands using Google

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this etc. But this is more of what you are looking for. As for the deletion an access times, you will have to code it up and figure out that logic.

http://pc.byethost17.com/scripts/php/?id=12

Comment: Welp, why not google, "how to get a folder size in php" and then hack that code to display it? Not going to do it for you, someone else might, but yea. Not me :)